# Create a second form for updating record in Python

Tags: python, sql, function, tkinter, window

I have created a simple program for updating a customer database. All of my functions work fine except the update function, which need to open in a new window so I can edit the record. I think I am close, but my new window does not show any text boxes or labels. My code is below in "create update function". Thank you.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
import sqlite3
from contextlib import closing
conn = None

class CustomerFrame(ttk.Frame):

    def __init__(self,parent):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, padding="10 10 10 10")
        self.pack(fill=tk.BOTH, expand=True)

        #create string variables for entry fields
        self.Name = tk.StringVar()
        self.Email = tk.StringVar()
        self.Delete = tk.StringVar()

        #create labels
        NameLabel = ttk.Label(self, text = "Name:").grid(column=0,row=0, sticky=tk.E)
        EmailLabel = ttk.Label(self, text = "Email:").grid(column=0,row=1, sticky=tk.E)
        DeleteLabel = ttk.Label(self, text = "Delete:").grid(column=0,row=2, sticky=tk.E)

        #create entry boxes
        NameEntry = ttk.Entry(self, width = 20, textvariable=self.Name).grid(column=1,row=0)
        EmailEntry = ttk.Entry(self, width = 20, textvariable=self.Email).grid(column=1,row=1)
        DeleteEntry= ttk.Entry(self, width = 20, textvariable=self.Delete).grid(column=1,row=2)

        #create buttons
        button1 = ttk.Button(self, text="View Records", command=self.display_customers).grid(column=2, row=0, ipadx=97)
        button2 = ttk.Button(self, text="Add Record", command=self.add_customer).grid(column=2, row=1, ipadx=98)
        button3 = ttk.Button(self, text="Delete Record", command=self.delete_customer).grid(column=2, row=2, ipadx=96)
        button4 = ttk.Button(self, text="Edit Record", command=self.update_customer).grid(column=2, row=3, ipadx=100)

        #add padding
        for child in self.winfo_children():
            child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=3)

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
#create update function        
    def update_customer(self):

        editor = tk.Tk()
        editor.title("Edit Screen")
        editor.geometry("400x600")
        editor.mainloop()


        editor.Name = tk.StringVar()
        editor.Email = tk.StringVar()

        Name_entry = ttk.Entry(editor, width = 20, textvariable=editor.Name).grid(column=1,row=0)
        Email_entry = ttk.Entry(editor, width = 20, textvariable=editor.Email).grid(column=1,row=1)     

#---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
#define the callback methods for buttons   
    def add_customer(self):

        name = self.NameText.get()
        email = self.EmailText.get()

        conn = sqlite3.connect("inventory.sqlite")
        c = conn.cursor()
        with closing(conn.cursor()) as C:
            sql = '''INSERT INTO Customers (name, email)
                 VALUES (?, ?)'''
            c.execute(sql, (name, email))   
        conn.commit()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------    
#create function to delete record based on ID entry
    def delete_customer(self):  

        conn = sqlite3.connect("inventory.sqlite")
        c = conn.cursor()
        with closing(conn.cursor()) as C:  
            c.execute("DELETE from customers WHERE customerID = " + self.Delete.get())     
            conn.commit()

#----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------        
#create function to display table contents
    def display_customers(self):   

        conn = sqlite3.connect("inventory.sqlite")
        c = conn.cursor()

        query = '''SELECT * FROM Customers'''
        c.execute(query)

        with closing(conn.cursor()) as c:
            #query the database
            query = '''SELECT * FROM Customers'''
            c.execute(query)
            customers = c.fetchall()
            print(customers)

            #loop through results, format tuple
            print_customers = ''
            for customer in customers:
                print_customers += str(customer[0]) + " | " + str(customer[1]) + " | " + str(customer[2]) + "\n"

            query_label = ttk.Label(self, text=print_customers)
            query_label.grid(row=4, column=0, columnspan=4)

            #Commit Changes
            conn.commit()


if __name__ == "__main__":     
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Customer Screen")
    CustomerFrame(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Read [Why are multiple instances of Tk discouraged?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48045508/7414759)
and [When to use the Toplevel Widget](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/toplevel.htm) and [Tkinter understanding mainloop](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29158947/7414759)

Comment: From reading, sounds like I have the option to create another file, or make use of the toplevel widget instead for my new window. Am I on the right track?

Comment: ***make use of the toplevel widget***: Yes

Answer (score 0):

Using the toplevel widget that @stovfl mentioned, I was able to edit my code. It works now (opens a new window with the correct data to edit). My book does not go over toplevelwidget so thank you. Here is my new update function if others need.

```
def update_customer(self):    
    #Create widget 
    top1 = Toplevel(self)     
    #Define title for window 
    top1.title("Edit Customer Screen") 
    #Create label 
    NameEditLabel = ttk.Label(top1, text = "Name:").grid(column=0,row=0, sticky=tk.E)
    EmailEditLabel = ttk.Label(top1, text = "Email:").grid(column=0,row=1, sticky=tk.E)    
    #Create text boxes
    NameEditBox = ttk.Entry(top1, width=20)
    #.grids must be on seperate line or causes Nonetype error?
    NameEditBox.grid(column=1,row=0)
    EmailEditBox = ttk.Entry(top1, width = 20)
    EmailEditBox.grid(column=1,row=1)     
    #Create buttons
    ButtonSave = ttk.Button(top1, text="Save Record").grid(column=1, row=2, ipadx=97)    
    #Set padding
    for child in top1.winfo_children():
        child.grid_configure(padx=5, pady=3)

    #Create database connection
    conn = sqlite3.connect("inventory.sqlite")      
    #create cursor
    c = conn.cursor()    
    #create variable
    record_id = self.Delete.get()    
    #Query the database
    with closing(conn.cursor()) as C:  
        c.execute("SELECT * FROM customers WHERE customerID = " + record_id)
        customers = c.fetchall()        
    #loop through results
        for customer in customers:
            NameEditBox.insert(0, customer[1])
            EmailEditBox.insert(0, customer[2])
```